# GRPC spawning large number of threads and not cleaning them

Tags: python, grpc

Im using GRPC version 1.9.0 python and i am noticing that GRPC is spawning a lot of threads when the request rate increasing and not releasing them back.

I m using standard server option but it seems like something is wrong

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=settings.max_workers))
```

Lot of threads can be seen when viewing output from htop command

Comment: There is currently a bug in gRPC: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/14523

Comment: Can you quantify "a lot"? Is it more than `max_workers`?

Comment: Also what can you tell us about the platform on which you're seeing this? Are you able to share code that demonstrates the problem?